# Find the range of Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

The range of Legendre polynomials in the `Reals` domain is [-1, 1]. How can we calculate it using `FunctionRange` or other MMA code?

```
FunctionRange[{LegendreP[l, x], Element[x, Reals] && Abs[x] <= 1 && Element[l, Integers] && l > 0}, x, y]
```

(*Unable to find the range with the available methods. *)

Comment: As the Legendre polynomials are polynomials, the function range in the reals extends to infinity. The function range in the interval [-1,1]  is [-1,1]

Comment: For even degree $l$, the min over $[-1,1]$ is $\ge -1/2$ and increases with $l$. For odd degree, the min is $-1$.

Comment: FWIW: `Unevaluated@LegendreP[l, Root[Function[x, (-1 - l)  x  LegendreP[l, x] + (1 + l)  LegendreP[1 + l, x]], If[Mod[l, 2] == 0, 2, 1]]] <= y <= 1 /. l -> 112 // 
 N[#, 16] &` -- Throws an error without a numeric positive integer value for `l`, though.

Comment: `FunctionRange[{LegendreP[24, x], RealAbs[x] <= 1}, x, y]` outputs `1/4194304 (676039 -    202811700  \
Root[-676039 + 66927861 #^2 - 1940907969 #^4 + 25786348731 #\^6 - 189099890694 #^8 + 842354058546 #^10 - 2397469243554 #\^12 + 4452442880886 #^14 - 5369122297539 #^16 + 4050390505161 #\^18 - 1735881645069 #^20 + 322476036831 #^22& , 1, 0]^2 + 
    10039179150  \Root[-676039 + 66927861 #^2 - 1940907969 #^4 + 25786348731 #\^6 - 189099890694 #^8 + 842354058546 #^10 - 2397469243554 #\
^12 + 4452442880886 #^14 - 5369122297539 #^16 + 4050390505161 #\^18 -     ...`

Comment: `+ 66927861 #^2 - 1940907969 #^4 + 25786348731 #\
^6 - 189099890694 #^8 + 842354058546 #^10 - 2397469243554 #\
^12 + 4452442880886 #^14 - 5369122297539 #^16 + 4050390505161 #\^18 - 1735881645069 #^20 + 322476036831 #^22& , 1, 0]^24) <= y <= 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
FunctionRange[{LegendreP[l, x], RealAbs[x] <= 1 && Element[l, Integers] && l > 0}, {x, l}, y, Method -> {"Reduced" -> True}]
```

(* -1. <= y <= 1. *)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this answers the question. In your own question statement, you said the domain was $[-1,]$, not $[-1,1] \times {\Bbb Z}^+$. You implied that $l$ was a parameter and explicitly stated $x$ was the only variable.

Comment: @Goofy In my question, both `x` and `l` are variables, and it's possible that a coding error in the question led to your misunderstanding. I did not intend to obtain an analytical expression for the minimum value of the Legendre polynomial over the interval [-1, 1] (where `l` is a parameter and `x` is a variable, and `l` is even), as this seems not very straightforward. However, for specific values assigned to `l`, such as `l ->112`, determining the range of the Legendre polynomial over [-1, 1]: `FunctionRange[{LegendreP[112, x], RealAbs[x] <= 1.0}, x, y]`  (* -0.402798 <= y <= 1.  *)